# Print method with user classes

Tags: r, data.table, r-s3

I'm experimenting with `S3-class` methods and generic functions, but I'm having an issue which I think highlights a misunderstanding in my thinking. Perhaps I'm getting confused with how printing works, or how storing `values` and `attributes` works internally?

I've tried to google around to no avail, possibly because I'm not too sure what I'm looking for.

## Setup

```
library(data.table)

# trivial data
dt <- CJ(letter = c("A", "B", "C"), number = 1:4)

# -- generic functions
coverage <- function (x, ...) {
  UseMethod("coverage", x)
}

prettyprint <- function (x, ...) {
  UseMethod("prettyprint", x)
}
```

## Class methods

```
# coverage method to find % of data.table satisfying an expr
coverage.data.table <- function(dt, subset, desc) {
  e <- parse(text = subset)  # parse condition to expression
  coverage <- dt[eval(e), .N]/dt[, .N]  # express coverage as a percent 
  class(coverage) <- c("coverage", class(coverage))  # set as 'coverage' class
  attributes(coverage)[["desc"]] <- desc  # carry description for printing
  coverage
}

# human readable data.table coverage
prettyprint.coverage <- function(coverage) {
  desc <- attributes(coverage)[["desc"]]
  paste0(round(coverage*100, 2), "% ", desc)
}

# normal printing
print.coverage <- function(coverage) {

  # unsure what to put in here such that I can use
  # this value with standard other operations such 
  # as multiplication

}

coverageB <- coverage(dt, "letter == \"B\"", "of data.table is in B")

> coverageB  # prints nothing as expected from empty function
> prettyprint(coverageB)
  [1] "33.33% of data.table is in B"
```

Printing  `coverageB` without loading `print.coverage` gives

```
> coverageB
[1] 0.3333333
attr(,"class")
[1] "coverage" "numeric" 
attr(,"desc")
[1] "of data.table is in B"
```

where I'd like some way to print just the `0.3333333`.

Help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

(As a side note, I'm sure that `eval(parse(...))` statement is not the right way to do things. Any pointers there would be appreciated too.)

I also wasn't sure what to title this - if anyone has any more appropriate suggestion I'm happy to change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two better possibilities, the first following your approach (which might be faster due to automatic indexing, but I haven't benchmarked):

```
coverage.data.table <- function(dt, subset, desc) {
  coverage <- dt[eval(substitute(subset)), .N]/dt[, .N]  # express coverage as a percent 
  #coverage <- dt[, mean(eval(substitute(subset)))]  # express coverage as a percent 
  class(coverage) <- c("coverage", class(coverage))  # set as 'coverage' class
  attributes(coverage)[["desc"]] <- desc  # carry description for printing
  coverage
}
```

Then you call it like this:

```
coverageB <- coverage(dt, letter == "B", "of data.table is in B")
```

Here is a `print` method that uses `c` to remove all attributes (see its documentation):

```
# normal printing
print.coverage <- function(coverage) {
  print.default(c(coverage))
} 

coverageB
#[1] 0.3333333
prettyprint(coverageB)
#[1] "33.33% of data.table is in B"
```

However, I don't understand your comments regarding the `print` method. The `print` method is in no way connected to multiplication.

Comment: I would never have guessed `c` would be the answer.. Thanks very much @Roland. On the last comment, I realised the print/multiplication bit isn't clear but left it as it didn't seem too important.. Originally when I tried this, I carried the exact figure as an attribute as well and displayed the attribute using print - but in that case I couldn't edit it in the expected manner.

Comment: I made a mistake in the original question and wrote `CJ(letter -> c("A", "B", "C"), number -> 1:4)` which results in `letter` existing in the global scope which means that the `dt[(subset), .N]/dt[, .N]` line worked. Without `letter` in the global scope I'm given the error "`letter not found`". Is there anyway to have something that works like this, after correcting my initial error?